# Why do threads keep uploading in my app and how can I control them?

Tags: android

Good afternoon:
I am making an app in Android Studio Java that uses fragments and in one of those fragments I have an "icon flag" that represents activation or deactivation states of elements in a database.
These icons are activated or not depending on values in a record from an external database.
To capture the values from the database registry, I use a handler.postdelayed that reads the values every second and, depending on them, activates or not the icons on the screen.
Everything works, but there is always a but, after a while of having the app open and using it, it turns off and gives a memory full error.

Using the android studio profiler, I observe that threads are generated for network requests (volley) and those threads do not stop increasing in number.
Could that be the cause of the stop?
Should I be worried about the large number of threads that are generated?
Is there a way to, once the data is received, eliminate the corresponding thread to "keep it at bay"?
I have tried with handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); in the onPause of the fragment, and it seems to me that it only deletes a thread.

What I can do?

I await your suggestions.
Thank you and happy holidays.

P.D.: sorry my english, is google translate.

I tested the app and it works, but the threads keep increasing. I tried handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); And it doesn't do anything

Comment: Solved, using a singleton keeps threads at bay